# Cross platform bash profile

Tags: linux, cross-platform

I want to create cross-platform bash_profile script, the script should identify which OS it's in (linux, cygwin, osx), what is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `uname -o`, which prints the name of the operating system. You can then check it by using a `case`.